# can flexbox dynamically size blocks?

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm trying to use flexbox to automatically size the .filler elements to be of equal height and take the available space based on the size of the element #right.  If #right is shorter than #box then .filler elements should be 0 height.

I can trick it with background-color on #left but was wondering if there is a way to target .filler

```css
.container{
display:flex;
}

#left,#right,.filler{
width:50vw;
}

#left{
display:flex;
flex-direction:column;
justify-content:center;
background-color:pink;
}

.filler{
background-color:blue;
}

#box{
width:50vw;
height:33.33vw;
background-color:green;
margin:auto;
}

#right{
height:75vw;
border:solid 2px black;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div id='left'>
    <div class='filler'></div>
    <div id='box'></div>
    <div class='filler'></div>
  </div>
  <div id='right'>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: why not margin:auto on green box?

Comment: doesn't seem to do anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.filler {
    background-color:red;
  flex-grow:1;
}
```

Use this property

Answer (score 1):

**By using Flex-grow property**

You have to connect each item with a class named "flex-grow: 1" to enhance each other items in respect to themselve.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.flex-container > div {
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
  color: white;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 75px;
  font-size: 30px;
}
  
#left,#right{
width:50vw;

}

#left{
flex-direction:column;  
}


#right{
height:100vw;
border:solid 2px black;
background-color:black;  
}
  
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>The flex-grow Property</h1>

<p>The items align itself as per height and width of each other</p>

<div class="flex-container">
  <div style="flex-grow: 1"><div id="right">right</div></div>
  <div style="flex-grow: 1"><div id='left'>left</div></div>
 
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: seems like the right direction but doesn't provide working example